# How to clear the errors for microprocessor design

Tags: verilog

Am designing a microprocessor.It works like as follows

1.During write operation( cen low,(wr ,msel,mclk, male)->high),whatever content on **adr** should be placed on **adbus** (multiplexed inout) to find address location of a memory. After that whatever the data available on **din** should be placed in adbus again for writing up the memory.

2.During read  operation(now **wr** is low to indicate read operation) again **addr** content should be placed in **adbus**. All the above movement of content should take place at **posedge of clk**. But only in read opeartion whatever the data present in adbus should be driven onto **dout** at **negedge of clk**.

additional details

a. **cen** when low then only access read and write operation

b. **mwr** when high adbus carries write data

c. **male** memory add. latch enable, when high carries add. info.

d. **mrd** when high, adbus carries read data and driven by memory **after falling edge of clk**

e. **msel** chip enable(should be high)

f. **mclk** clout out to memory. This one is a tricky part->read data is available on **adbus** after falling edge of **mclk**

only one of **mwr**, **mrd**, **male** can be high in a clock cycle and read/write happens at the latched add. in memory(don't know what it means actually!!!)

```
module mem_controller(addr,din,cen,wr,clk,dout,mclk,male,msel,mwr,mrd,adbus);
input  [7:0] addr;
input  [7:0] din;
input cen,wr,clk;
output reg [7:0] dout;
output mclk,male,msel,mwr,mrd;
inout [7:0] adbus;
wire [7:0] adbus;

initial
    clk = 1'b1;

//  assign addr  = 8'b01010101;
//  assign din   = 8'b01111111;
//  assign dout  = 8'b10000000;
//  assign adbus = 8'b10101111;

assign male = 1'b0;
assign wr   = 1'b0;
assign msel = 1'b0;
assign mwr  = 1'b0;
assign mwd  = 1'b0;
assign cen  = 1'b1;

always
   #10 clk = ~clk;
initial 
begin
   #20 cen  = 1'b0;
   #10 wr = 1'b1;
   #10 msel = 1'b1;
   #10 mclk = 1'b1;
   #10 male = 1'b1;
   #20 male = 1'b0;
   #20 mwr  = 1'b1;
   #20 mwr = 1'b0;
   #20 wr = 1'b0;
   #20 male = 1'b1;
   #20 male = 1'b0;
   #20 mrd  = 1'b1;
   #20 mrd  = 1'b0;
   #20 msel = 1'b1;
   #0 mclk = 1'b0;

   #20 cen  = 1'b1;

   #20 $finish;
end

always @(posedge clk) 
  begin
   if      ((!cen) &&   wr  && msel && mclk && male) 
adbus =addr;

   else if ((!cen) &&   wr  && msel && mclk && mwr)   
 adbus = din;

   else if ((!cen) && (!wr) && msel && mclk && male) 
adbus = addr;
end

always @(negedge clk) 
begin
   if((!cen) && (!wr) && msel && mclk && mrd)
      dout = adbus;
end 

endmodule
```

The errors shown are

> **Reference to vector wire 'adbus' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue**

and

> **Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment**

also i am not able to make inout as reg(it would show the following error)

> **"Illegal redeclaration of inout 'adbus' as a reg"**

please help out...

Comment: Please format your code. Very hard to read.

Comment: 1.if i define adbus as register like " reg[7:0] adbus;" the following error is shown "Illegal redeclaration of inout 'adbus' as a reg"  and 2.if i use "inout reg [7:0] adbus;" it will sho error as "'adbus' has not been declared" and"Port reference 'adbus' was not declared as input, inout or output"

Comment: @user3388605 you taken on more then you can handle by adding on cross clock domain before understanding the fundamentals of RTL design. Start with a smaller single-clock project.

Answer (score 2):

- The `initial blocks` need to be moved to a test bench.
- You cannot connect the outputs with an `assign` statement and directly change the values in an initial block.
- Synchrounus logic should use non-blocking (`<=`)
- `inout` is a tri-state which need to be assigned as:

  - `assign adbus = output_enable ? adbus_out : 8'bz;`
- The `clk` driver (`always #10 clk = ~clk;`) needs to be in the test bench.

Comment: 1.which initial blocks shouid i need to move to testbench(sorry am new to verilog) and
2. is it possible to change the values in an initial block without "assign"
3.and i didnt understood the statement "assign adbus = output_enable ? adbus_out ? 8'bz;"

Comment: `initial` blocks are only allowed in test-benches and non-synthesizable behavioral models. If the Design is for FPGA, initial blocks with no delay component (`#()`, `@()`, `wait()`, etc.) are allowed. In your case, it looks like all the initial blocks.

Comment: You need to do so research in your own, or at least demonstrate effort. Search for verilog tri-state on the web or in a verilog book.

Comment: @Greg: did you mean: `? :`?

Comment: thanx for the reply Greg


i have used "assign adbus = mwr? din : 8'bz;" but still its showing the same error :"Reference to vector wire 'adbus' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue" . And the same error will come even if i declare adbus as trireg. :(

Comment: @Qiu, thanks for catching that

Comment: @user3388605. `inout` needs to be a `wire`, not a `reg`